# View size control in iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I am designing one of my view in my

```
MainView
```

I am plan to have a smaller View instance in my `MainView`. What I need to do is: 
When the app is running on iPhone, the view size should be square and its width is equal to the screen's with. When the app is running  on iPad, the width should be 1/3 of the screen's width.

So how to define different width ratio on iPhone and iPad. How to approach this? Can I do this in storyboard file or I have to do this by code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard file you will need to create variations for traits.  There is a button in the lower right hand side of the storyboard inspector that says "Vary for Traits", using this you can set constraints to have different constant values depending on the device size(iPad/iPhone).

In this case you can pin the leading and trailing edges of the smaller view to the sides of the parent view, and for the iPhone vary the trait to be equal to zero, while the iPads space can be set to 10 points(however many points of space you want).

Creating adaptive UI's can be and is a rather complex subject, so if you have no experience, like @Zack Leonidas Hamblen said check out that article and read up to get a better understanding on what is happening and how to use it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your constraints in Storyboard, create an `@IBOutlet` for the constraint and do something like:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    // set the width constraint = 1/3 of the screen width
} else {
    // set constraint = screen width
}
```